# Is it feasible to utilize QEMU built-in gdbserver to debug a program running in the guest OS in QEMU?

Tags: qemu, gdbserver

I understand that QEMU built-in gdbserver can be used to debug kernel or bare-metal program. But I am curious that if it is possible to use QEMU built-in gdbserver to debug a program running in guest os in QEMU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it won't be pleasant.  Don't be surprised if execution bounces around as the kernel services external interrupts, and switches to other tasks. I'd recommend using a normal user-mode debugger inside the VM if possible.